# Importing CSV file into list python

Tags: python, csv

I've a little problem here. I need to read a txt file and store it into a list, I'm already doing that... but the problem is that I need to manipulate some columns like multiplying then by 30 and so forth so on. (I'm still learning python) (Its python 3.4)

The test.txt file:

```
Abacate;Para;PA;-1.1166667;-49.65
Abacate;Amazonas;AM;-3.9463889;-62.9038889
```

The code:

```
def readFile():
  with open('test.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=";")
    #reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        for (i,v) in enumerate(row):
            columns[i].append(v)
```

But, when I try to use

```
    for i in range(0,len(columns[3])):
        listTest.append(columns[3][i]*3)
```

The result is:

```
['-1.1166667-1.1166667-1.1166667']
['-1.1166667-1.1166667-1.1166667', '-3.9463889-3.9463889-3.9463889']
```

Expected:

```
['-3.3500001','-11.8391667']
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is reading the numbers as strings, so when you do the `*3` it thinks "Ah! Matt wants me to put the the string three times in a row!"

If you just convert it to a float first, it'll be fine:

```
for i in range(0,len(columns[3])):
    listTest.append(float(columns[3][i])*3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the `columns[3][i]` into float like

```
listTest.append(float(columns[3][i])*3)
```

Because

```
'any_string'*3
>>any_stringany_stringany_string
 100*3
>>300
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import csv
def readFile(infilepath):
    answer = []
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        for *_head, a, _b in csv.reader(infile, delimiter';'):
            answer.append(float(a) * 3)
    return answer
```